# How can I see all of my commits to a repository regardless of branch?

Tags: git, github

I know that I can use `git log` to see the commits on the current branch. Is there a way to see all of *my* commits over some period of time? I'm working on a project with other developers and we meet regularly to give progress reports on our various efforts. Most of the time I'm working on a single branch, but often I'll have a PR in the queue and will begin another branch while I wait for a review. During our meetings, if I only worked on one branch, `git log` is an easy way to see what I've accomplished since the last meeting. But if I've worked on multiple branches, perhaps even three, since the last meeting, it would be nice if there were a command that listed only my commits across branches.

Note this project is hosted on GitHub, so maybe there's a way to do it there if not on the command line.

Comment: For command-line Git, use `git log --all --author=...` (fill in the dots with your author name/email).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this on git CLI.

```
git fetch # to fetch latest branch information from remote to local
git log --all --author="your_email"
```

Comment: For `git fetch`, the `--all` flag never means *all branches*. It always means *all remotes*. Unless you have more than one remote, it does nothing at all. The rule for beginners is: never use `git fetch --all`. (For `git log` it does have the intended meaning and is required, it's just `git fetch` that's weird here.)